# Select values between square brackets and quotes in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I've used the following code to concatenate results

```
SELECT 
COLLECT_LIST(col_name) AS my_col
FROM my_table
```

This somewhat achieves my desired result, output as follows:

```
["car","motorcycle","bus"]
["train","boat"]
["airplane","bicycle"]
```

However, I need to remove the square brackets and quotes before surfacing in the subsequent business report.

I have tried various iterations of the following to no avail:

```
regexp_extract(my_col,'\\[|\\]','')
```

This gives the error message

> java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 6:0 Wrong arguments '''': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with (array, string, string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(string, string)  *FUNC*(string, string, int)

How can I achieve my desired result of...

```
car, motorcycle
train, boat
airplane, bicycle
```

Is regex_replace function the best way of doing this?

Guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably  `SELECT 
concat_ws(', ', collect_set(col_name)) AS my_col
FROM my_table` will do.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew this is perfect and a much better solution for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concat_ws` to join the string array from the very beginning:

```
SELECT concat_ws(', ', collect_set(col_name)) AS my_col FROM my_table
       ^ ---------------------------------- ^
```

The [`concat_ws`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) is more appropriate since you have an array of strings, not a single string.

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> with t1 as (select cast(1 as string) as col1 union  select cast(2 as string) as col1 union  select cast(3 as string) as col1) select collect_set(col1), concat_ws(',', collect_set(col1)) from t1;
OK
["1","2","3"]   1,2,3
Time taken: 95.27 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

> > concat_ws accepts only array of string values

If the number of items are fixed then you can also use

```
hive> with t1 as (select cast(1 as string) as col1 union  select cast(2 as string) as col1 union  select cast(3 as string) as col1) select concat(collect_set(col1)[0], ',' ,collect_set(col1)[1], ',', collect_set(col1)[2]) from t1;
```